# Using Index and Match in Excel VBA VLookup function

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, vlookup, excel-2013

I have an excel formula that I use often that does a `VLookup`. It has an embedded `Index/Match` that gives the last numeric value in the "M" Column. 
The Worksheet formula is this:

```
=VLOOKUP(INDEX($M$10:$M75,MATCH(9.99999999999999E+307,$M$10:$M75)),Data,4)
```

Cell `$M75` being the cell of the row this formula is in.  There are numeric, non-numeric and blank cells in Column M but the ID's that I want are always numeric.

So I am trying to write a custom function that would let me simply write `=current()`

Here is what I have:

```
Function Current()
  Dim LookupRange As Variant
  Dim indexVar As Variant
  LookupRange = Range("$M$1:M" & ActiveCell.Row)
  indexVar = Application.Index(Range(LookupRange), Application.Match(9.99999999999999E+307, Range(LookupRange)))
  Current = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(indexVar, Worksheets("Info").Range("Data"), 4)
End Function
```

I have tried using different variable types (String, Long, Variant) but I can't seem to get the function to work. 
I don't know if this is enough info but can anyone see if I am missing something? 
I only get `#VALUE!`
Using Excel 2013 on Windows 7

Comment: Before going to VBA, is your excel function returning correct results?

Comment: Step through your code and determine **1)** is the value assigned to `LookupRange` correct?  **2)** is the value assigned to `indexVar` correct?

Comment: @sam092 - My original formula functions correctly.

Comment: @DavidZemens - My LookupRange shows the correct range if I make it a string. And if I make the indexVar a string and use a macro to insert a vLookup formula into a cell on my sheet it gives the correct ID number. But Strings don't work when I try doing the Vlookup in VBA.

Comment: OK let me try a few things...

Comment: `LookupRange` is a variant array. This will raise a `Type Mismatch` in the assignment to `indexVar`... If I `Dim LookupRange As String` I also get a `Type Mismatch` error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some problems with this code that are at odds with your description.

- `LookupRange` is a variant array. When I test this, it raises a `1004 Method 'Range' of object '_Global' failed` error in the assignment to `indexVar`.
- If I `Dim LookupRange As String` per your comments, I also get a `Type Mismatch` error.

Since `LookupRange` should be a range, I declare it as a range, and use the `Set` keyword in the assignment statement.

```
Set lookupRange = Range("$M$10:$M" & ActiveCell.Row)
```

- Possible typo in your assignment to `lookupRange`. In your formula, originally you use `$M$1`, but in the function you use `$M$10`.

If you start this range at `$M$10`, and try to evaluate the formula in any cell between row 1-9, you will get an error.

On a related note, **if there are no numeric values** in the `lookupRange`, this will return an error, e.g., putting `Current()` in cell `M2` makes a lookup range of `M1:M2`, wherein I have no numeric data.

[image]

I am not sure how you want to handle this, but my answer includes one way to avoid that error.  You can modify as needed.  Finally:

- Relying on `ActiveCell.Row` seems like a bad idea, since this formula may recalculate with undesired results.

Instead, make this a required argument for the formula, which you can then call from the worksheet like: `=Current(Row())`.

Putting it all together, I think this should work, and I provide an example/escape for the match not found error.
:

```
Public Function Current(r As Long)
    Const bigNumber As Double = 9.99999999999999E+307
    Dim wsInfo As Worksheet: Set wsInfo = Worksheets("Info")
    Dim lookupRange As Range
    Dim indexVar As Long
    Dim myVal As Variant

    Set lookupRange = Range("$M$1:$M" & r)
    If Not Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(lookupRange) = 0 Then
        indexVar = Application.Index(lookupRange, Application.Match(bigNumber, lookupRange))
        myVal = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(indexVar, wsInfo.Range("Data"), 4)
    Else:
        myVal = "No numbers found in: " & lookupRange.Address
    End If
    Current = myVal

End Function
```

**UPDATE FROM COMMENTS**

You can add `Application.Volatile`[link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa213653(v=office.11).aspx) before the variable declarations.  This should force re-calculation:

> whenever calculation occurs in any cells on the worksheet.

However, this will not force calculation when values on other worksheets (e.g., your `Worksheets("Info")` is another worksheet) change.

To force recalculation every time you active the sheet containing the `=Current(Row())` function, you could put this in the worksheet's code module:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    Me.Calculate
End Sub
```

This is probably as close as you can get -- to replicating the native `VLOOKUP` functionality without actually using a `VLOOKUP` formula.

**Additional notes:**

Favoring correctly/strongly-typed variables, I declare `indexVar as Long` and create a double-precision variable for `9.99999999999999E+307` (it's just easier to work with this way).  I also create a worksheet object variable, again, I find them easier to work with.

Comment: That works and gives me the correct information. The interesting thing is it doesn't recalculate if the number it would have found changes. Is this because of the index/match?

Comment: It will update if I enter the cell but not by itself as other Vlookup functions do. Is this because of the index/match only executes once when the function is entered?

Comment: This isn't a `Vlookup` function :) it's simply using the `Vlookup` method to search for a matching offset value.  I'll add some additional comments to my answer to clarify/suggest what you might do.

Comment: If this solves your problem @Brad please mark the answer as "Accepted".  Cheers!

Comment: Thank you for all your help. It's weird because I have a function that uses the same vlookup method except instead of calculating 'indexVar' with index/match I give it a cell that contains a index/match formula. And that recalculates any time there is a change.

Comment: The cell which contains the index/match formula recalculates as a worksheet function should, if its references change values, just as if you *entered* the cell to manually force recalculation.  So in this case, it is the reference to a volatile cell which forces the recalculation. I'm pretty sure that formulas always re-calculate when a reference changes. The difference with function `Current` is that the reference (`Row()`) does not change, so you need another method to force calculation.