# Calculation in a big worksheet

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have an Excel worksheet with a maximum of 150000 rows of data spreaded on nearly 50 columns. It's all values.

I'm adding new rows to the worksheet (usually no more than 20000 rows at a time) with VBA and there is actually a column where the results need to be calculated. So that could be 20 000 formulas (maximum) to evaluate. If I try `Worksheet.Calculate`, I get the error described on this page: http://support2.microsoft.com/kb/2655178

One alternative is to evaluate the cells one by one with VBA using the `Range.Calculate` method with a `For` loop. It does work and gets the job done but it takes a huge time to loop through the cells.

Is there any alternative or optimisation I could do? After copying the new rows, this is the formula I'm adding and trying to evaluate for a maximum of 20k cells (in the same column):

```vb
With ActiveSheet
    .Cells(lastRow, lastCol - 1).FormulaArray = "=IFERROR(LEFT($AK" & lastRow & ",LEN($AK" & lastRow & ")-2-LEN(INDEX($AK:$AK,MATCH(1,($A:$A=$A" & lastRow & ")*($AQ:$AQ=INDEX(Month,1,MATCH($AQ" & lastRow & ",Month,0)-1)),0)))),$AK" & lastRow & ")"
    .Range("AP" & lastRow).AutoFill .Range("AP" & lastRow & ":AP" & .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row)
    .Range(.Cells(lastRow, lastCol - 1), .Cells(.Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row, lastCol - 1)).Value = .Range(.Cells(lastRow, lastCol - 1), .Cells(.Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row, lastCol - 1)).Value
End With
```

`LastCol - 1` is the column with the calculations (always corresponds to column AP), `LastRow` is evaluated before importing the new rows (so it is basically the first row of the new data in the above example). `Application.ScreenUpdating` is set to false and `Application.Calculation` is set to `xlCalculationManual`.

Excel returns me an error if I have more than a certain number of rows overall in the worksheet (the number of cells with formulas is always less thank 20k) if I try this:

```
ActiveSheet.Calculate
```

This however will work but takes hours:

```
For i = lastRow To .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
    ActiveWorksheet.Range("AP" & i).Calculate
Next i
```

Cells with formulas are always in column AP and only for new rows of data because, as said previously, the results are converted to values after the calculations.

---

To better explain why I need the Excel formula, here is an example of the data I have:

```
ID|Users                      |Month
-----------------------------------------
 1|AA1234                     |September
 2|BB1234 AA1234              |September
 1|BB1234 AA1234              |October
 2|AA1234 CC1234 BB1234 AA1234|October
```

I want a new column for the users of the current month for every IDs, so for example in October for the ID 2, I want the users `AA1234 CC1234` since we know that the 2 other users have actually worked on that ID not in October but in September. I have a named range `Month = {"January", ..., {"December"}` in my workbook.

Comment: Have you tried turning the automatic calculation off? ````ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Summary").EnableCalculation = False```` then paste your script that works, followed by ````ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Summary").EnableCalculation = True````

Comment: `EnableCalculation` is already `True` at the moment, disabling it before copying the values shouldn't really do much since `Application.Calculation` is `xlCalculationManual`. The reason why all the calculations are done manually is because another worksheet has over 200k formulas (and surprisingly, doing a `.Calculate` of this worksheet works without any problem but it's *only* 200 rows by 100 cols of data which is less cells (but more formulas) than in my example above).

Comment: It isn't a matter of the number of formulas; what's killing your calculation resources is an array formula that uses full column references. Cutting the full columns references down to the 150K rows of actual data you have would help but array processing consumes resources at a ever-increasing logarithmic rate. I tried to decipher your formula to see if newer (more efficient) 2010 functions could be applied but without sample data the latter section seems circular in logic. Perhaps you can redact some data and post it somewhere. If you do, leave one of the array formulas in column AP.

Comment: Column AK is a bunch of user IDs and I'm looking at the data of the last month to actually get the users of the current month in column AP, so for example if I have `CC1234 BB1234 AA1234` in AK for a row with `AQ="September"` and I have `DD1234 AA1234 CC1234 BB1234 AA1234` for the row with the same ID (column A) but with `AQ="October"`, I want `AP="DD1234 AA1234"` for the October row.

Comment: Data sample added, not with all the 50 columns obviously since only 3 columns are actually useful for my original problem, all the other columns are just copy-pasted values used as references. Note that I'm using array formulas in my >200k formulas worksheet too without any problem but on limited range instead of columns.

Comment: You can always reduce the resource usage needed for calculating the formulas by **not-using** formulas. You can use temporary invisible sheets and VBA code that calculates the same things formulas would produce. It will just take little bit longer than Excel's built-in optimized functions

Comment: I have always been told to prefer Excel functions rather than VBA but yeah, I could obviously use VBA to achieve the same results. But I'm not sure it would be better than just loop through every cells to perform the Excel calculations, because with VBA I would actually have to loop through the entire worksheet for every formula I replace because of the INDEX/MATCH parts. I could try it.

Comment: I'm not sure if this: [Stack Overflow: Using Index and Match in Excel VBA VLookup function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19083649/using-index-and-match-in-excel-vba-vlookup-function) article provides the best hint or you'll need to click into some related article, but **you can** call some fast Excel functions from your VBA code

Comment: Not exactly the same thing, INDEX and MATCH helps to not use VLOOKUP which is the slower function. However, I will try to use defined range, I know the number of rows with VBA so I will use this to define the ranges and see if that helps.

Comment: It does work with limited range, so the problem is really array formulas with full colums references. @Jeeped You could post your comment as an answer and I'd appreciate some additionnal references about what Excel is really doing with full columns or full rows references since a limited range from 1 to 150k is working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is what @Jeeped commented on the original question but since he still didn't have posted it as an answer, here it is for clarity purposes:

> It isn't a matter of the number of formulas; what's killing your
>   calculation resources is an array formula that uses full column
>   references. Cutting the full columns references down to the 150K rows
>   of actual data you have would help but array processing consumes
>   resources at a ever-increasing logarithmic rate. I tried to decipher
>   your formula to see if newer (more efficient) 2010 functions could be
>   applied but without sample data the latter section seems circular in
>   logic. Perhaps you can redact some data and post it somewhere. If you
>   do, leave one of the array formulas in column AP.